# Requesting downvotes for mistaken tag synonyms

Tags: discussion

*Mea culpa*: I created a couple of tag synonym proposals backwards (on the synonym instead of the master). Since apparently they [cannot be deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364219/i-suggested-a-tag-synonym-but-now-id-like-to-remove-it) as such, could I request some concerted downvotes on my proposed synonyms so that they'll go away?

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/ci/synonyms
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/ant/synonyms

Comment: You have my vote, then, I'll post a tweet tomorrow and see if I can drum up some more votes for you.

Comment: aye aye, captain. Don't have enough score on the ci tag to vote, but no problems on the ant tag.

Comment: Just to be clear, we aren't downvoting this post as well, right? :p

Comment: @DerekF want to see if we can trigger an integer underflow on the vote count?

Comment: `ant` synonym destroyed! Just need one more vote on `ci`.

Comment: sheesh - I have done hundreds of deployments on Gearset yet I don't have enough rep to downvote `ci` ... sorry David

Comment: Yeah, the rep requirements *really* don't work well for smaller tags/exchanges.

Comment: Paging @JayantDas, Jayant Das, please report to meta to help kill a bad tag synonym.

Comment: LOL! Yup, there are some tags that only a few old timers who haven't been seen in eons can vote on.

Comment: @DerekF - I landed up here while searching how to create a tag, and see that you had mentioned me in the comment. Interestingly, your *page* never reached me on 12/15 :) (I went back and checked all the inbox items, and couldn't find at all). I hope this is resolved by now.

Comment: @JayantDas how strange. I knew that your name wouldn't come up in the autocomplete, but I thought it would have sent you a notification. I can see why pinging someone not involved with a particular question wouldn't notify them (else everyone would be @-ing sfdcfox day and night). I wonder if starting a chat would've worked... anyway, looks like the ci tag synonym has been obliterated.

Comment: @DerekF and strange enough, it did notify now, seems the name did autocomplete now, most likely I put a comment.  *else everyone would be @-ing sfdcfox day and night* -- so true, rofl!